# Проверка пересечения луча и отрезка (по координатам)

Tags: алгоритм

Отрезок и луч задаются координатами (отрезок координатами концов, луч координатами начала и произвольной точки)

Как проверить, будут ли они пересекаться?

Comment: Получаете точку пересечения прямых, проверяете принадлежит ли она  отрезку и лучу.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обычно делают так: сначала находят точку пересечения прямых

```
struct pt {
    double x, y;
};

struct line {
    double a, b, c;
};

const double EPS = 1e-9;

double det (double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    return a * d - b * c;
}

bool intersect (line m, line n, pt & res) {
    double zn = det (m.a, m.b, n.a, n.b);
    if (abs (zn) < EPS)
        return false;
    res.x = - det (m.c, m.b, n.c, n.b) / zn;
    res.y = - det (m.a, m.c, n.a, n.c) / zn;
    return true;
}
```

http://e-maxx.ru/algo/lines_intersection

Потом проверяют что эта точка лежит на отрезке. Например

`res.x >= x0 && res.x <= x1 && res.y >= y0 && res.y <= y1`

Потом проверяют что по нужную сторону на луче. Например

`(res.x > x0) == (x1 > x0) && (res.y > y0) == (y1 > y0)`.

В целом это всё чистая математика.

Comment: Не совсем понятна проверка стороны луча)
Но сделаю через скалярное произведение 2-х векторов (если >0, то сонаправлены, значит точка на луче). Спасибо больше за помощь!

Comment: @Limmy там написано что наша координата по `x` лежит с той же стороны от начальной точки, что и 2 координата луча. Аналогично  по `y`.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а значат три переменные структуры `line`? Имеется ввиду координаты произвольной точки и угол прямой?

Comment: @VerNick нет. уравнение прямой имеет вид `ax + by + c = 0` вот эти 3 коээфициэнта. Понятно что можно нормировать.

Comment: Хорошо, я понял, спасибо!

Comment: >> res.x >= x0 && res.x <= x1 && res.y >= y0 && res.y <= y1
Это проверка, лежит ли точка в прямоугольнике, диагональю которого отрезок является. Для полноты надо проверить, лежит ли точка на прямой, образуемой краями отрезка

Comment: @MIKHANGO этого достаточно. точка лежит на пересечении прямых. осталось проверить что именно внутри отрезка а не на его продолжении. в целом половину условия можно убрать, и проверить только x или только y координату, не помню уже почему 7 лет назад так написал)

Answer (score -3):

L(xy) - луч начало, Lp(xy) - луч точка, A(xy), B(xy). result -?

```
boolean a = By < Lpy// при Lpx = Bx
boolean b = Ay < Lpy// при Lpy = Ax
result = !(a ^ b)
```

Comment: классно, а от `L(xy)` ничего не зависит?

Comment: L(xy) нужно чтобы найти Lpy, задание не найти точку а узнать пересикаются ли.

Comment: где обоснование этого алгоритма вобще ? или не могли бы вы пояснить что тут происходит ?

Comment: @МихаилКоломиец - Пожалуйста! Не удаляйте и не редактируйте Ваш предыдущий комментарий! :)

Comment: Первая строка начальные данные. 2 -  ищем координату y луча при координате х = координате х B точки прямой. 4 - если оба выражения одинаковы - результат не пересекаются