# Найти пересечение прямых, заданных координатами пар точек на них

Tags: javascript, математика, геометрия

Есть 2 отрезка 
AB - 1 отрезок 
CD - 2 отрезок
 
На вход поступают следующие данные 
A[x1, y1] B[x2, y2]
C[x3, y3] D[x4, y5]
Нужно найти мнимую точку пересечения (Координаты)
Картинка ниже (красный кружок), желательно решение на JS
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите вашу попытку, в чём проблема. Почему мы должны это делать?  Если вы не понимаете эту тему попробуйте поискать информацию, а не искать кто это сделает за вас.

Comment: Пересечение прямых? Или отрезков?  в любом случае такие вопросы наверняка уже были, попробуйте поискать

Comment: *Пересечение точек* — это круто...

Comment: Я очень слаб в геометрии и у меня стоит такая задача, я пытался найти решение, но совсем не могу понять как подставлять по координатам. Я искал, много искал, но не смог найти, вот и задал вопрос.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: Мда, оказывается, почти нет нормальных ответов по этой теме. Нашел только https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/533102/291659, к уравнению прямых только ещё надо прийти

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зададим прямые параметрическими уравнениями. Для первой прямой (пусть будет прямая A, задана точками A0, A1)

```
x(t) = ax0 + (ax1 - ax0) * t
y(t) = ay0 + (ay1 - ay0) * t
```

`t` - это параметр, равный нулю для точки A0, равный единице для точки A1, находится в диапазоне 0..1 для точек внутри отрезка A0A1 и т.д.

Для второй прямой (B)

```
x(u) = bx0 + (bx1 - bx0) * u
y(u) = by0 + (by1 - by0) * u
```

Прямые пересекаются в точке, в которой и X- и Y-координаты для обеих прямых совпадают, что приводит к следующей системе линейных уравнений относительно параметров `t` и `u`:

```
ax0 + (ax1 - ax0) * t = bx0 + (bx1 - bx0) * u
ay0 + (ay1 - ay0) * t = by0 + (by1 - by0) * u
```

Решаем систему, находим `t`, потом подставляем полученный параметр в первые уравнения для нахождения точки пересечения.

Иногда система может не иметь решений - когда прямые параллельны, или иметь бесконечное количество решений - когда прямые совпадают.

На Python:

```
def line_intersection(ax0, ay0, ax1, ay1, bx0, by0, bx1, by1):
    adx = ax1 - ax0
    ady = ay1 - ay0
    bdx = bx1 - bx0
    bdy = by1 - by0
    denom = bdy * adx - bdx * ady
    if denom == 0:    #прямые параллельны или совпадают
        return None
    t = (bdx * (ay0 - by0) + bdy * (bx0 - ax0)) / denom
    return (ax0 + adx * t, ay0 + ady * t)

print(line_intersection(0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 2, 1))
print(line_intersection(0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 4, 1))

>>> (1.5, 1.5)
>>> None
```

Если стоит задача различать совпадение и параллельность прямых, то нужно ещё внутри первого условия проверять

```
if (bx0 - ax0) * ady == (by0 - ay0) * adx: # прямые совпадают
```